# cannot manipulate a column in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table:

```
(f <- data.table(id1=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                 v=c(1,NA,NA,2,3,4),
                 key="id1"))
  id1  v
1:   1  1
2:   1  2
3:   2 NA
4:   2  3
5:   3 NA
6:   3  4
```

when I try to set missing `v` from the present value in the group:

```
> f[,v[is.na(v)] := v[which(!is.na(v))[1]], by="id1"]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'v' not found
Calls: [ -> [.data.table -> eval -> eval
```

Obviously, I am missing something very simple...

Comment: that feature doesn't exist yet - https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2793&group_id=240&atid=978

Comment: With that example, I guess you can use it in `i` instead of on the LHS of `:=`, though, since your condition does not depend on the id1 group you're in: `f[v%%2==0,v:=10L*v[1],by=id1]`

Comment: @Frank: please see edit, this is not quite what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one solution:

```
f[, v:={
  ok <- !is.na(v)
  ifelse(ok,v,v[ok][1])
}, by=id1]
```

---

Note that if `v` is entirely `NA` for one group, it will stay that way:

```
f  <- data.table(id1=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),v=c(1,NA,NA,2,3,4),key="id1")
ff <- rbind(f,list(4L,NA),list(4L,NA))
ff[,v:={ok <- !is.na(v);ifelse(ok,v,v[ok][1])},by=id1]
```