# Replacing for-loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to stop using for loops when I code but I have a bit of a problem representing a simple operation.

Let's say I am trying to do simple nearest-neighbour estimation on a dataset for a company that owns several restaurants. I have three features: City, Store, Month and one target function Sales. City,Store and Month are all represented with numbers: City takes values between 1-100, Store takes values between 1-50 and Month between 1-12.

Now, I want to replace this for-loop with an apply function:

```
for (c in 1:100){
 for (s in 1:50){
  for (m in 1:12){
   dat1$Sales[dat1$City==c & dat1$Store==s & dat1$Month==m & is.na(dat1$Sales)] <-
    mean(dat1$Sales[dat1$City==c & dat1$Store==s & dat1$Month==m & !is.na(dat1$Sales)])
  }
 }
}
```

What is the complexity of this apply function?

Many thanks!

Comment: Using a data.table, `dat1[,Sales:=Sales[!is.na(Sales)],by='c,s,m']`

Comment: Please review [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). A `dput()` of some of the data frame would be cool to help folks help you.

Comment: What is this doing? At first glance it just looks like you are removing the rows where sales is NA. Can you show us a little more of the data.frame?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I updated the question. I'm replacing each missing item with average of similar items. I didn't include snapshots of the dataset because it seems very easy and trivial. But I'm guessing it's not...

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the `mean`. In that case, `dat1[,Sales:=mean(Sales[!is.na(Sales)]),by='c,s,m']`

Comment: @Frank will that replace all of the `Sales` values with the mean or only those `Sales` which are `NA` ?

Comment: @JohnPaul Oh you are right, hmm. One probably inefficient way would be `dat1[,Sales:={mm=mean(Sales,na.rm=TRUE); ifelse(is.na(Sales),mm,Sales)},by='c,s,m']` I think

Answer (score 3):

Try using `aggregate`. It has a `formula` like interface that makes it easy to get the results of a function applied on parts of a `data.frame`. Then just assign the result to the place in `dat1` that needs it.

```
TempOut<- aggregate(Sales~City+Store+Month, FUN=mean,data=dat1)

dat1$Sales[is.na(dat1$Sales),]<-TempOut[TempOut$City==[dat1[is.na(dat1$Sales),]$City 
& TempOut$Store==[dat1[is.na(dat1$Sales),]$Store & TempOut$Month==
[dat1[is.na(dat1$Sales),]$Month,]$Sales
```

You could combine the creation of `TempOut` and assignment to `dat1$Sales` into one line, but that would have made this even harder to read. I don't have your data so I can't test this - but this should get you on the right track, even if there is a typo in there.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `data.table` way:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(dat1)

dat1[, Sales:={
  m=mean(Sales,na.rm=TRUE)
  replace(Sales, is.na(Sales), m)
},by=.(City, Store, Month)]
```

It would be nice to have something like `Sales[is.na(Sales)]:=...`, but this is just a [feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/571) right now. Here is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463385/cannot-manipulate-a-column-in-a-data-table).